# Output all form variables in javascript (similar to php's print_r())

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables

I'm simply looking to output all form names and their associated variables in an alert box to help me debug something. I'd just use firebug or whatever but the problem only exists on IE (and the IE developer tools don't seem very helpful in this case.)

I'm guessing I just need a for loop but I'm not sure how to provide it an array of form keys..

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using JSON + jquery:

```
var formObject = {};

$('form input, form textarea, form select').each(function(){
  formObject[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

alert(JSON.stringify(formObject));
```

**edit:**
in action
http://jsfiddle.net/RaPVf/

note: for ie 7 and below you need to include JSON2.js

Comment: Just an FYI, capitalizing the first letter of a variable name goes against the typical convention.

Comment: Almost, but this is just for elements called 'input', also all the values turned out empty for some reason. Still, it's a good start and I might be able to get it working from that.

Comment: Also, it'd be handy to have a non-jquery way of doing this :p Doesn't need to be clever.

Comment: I put in some other input types.

Comment: the real trick to it is the JSON.stringify serving as a print_r replacement.

Comment: Facepalm, it seems the site I needed it on is a compiled .net app I can't re-compile :// Which will lead me to a new question... still, question answered well so a tick for you.

Answer (score 1):

I took this question to have some fun navigating the DOM. Check it out and try it ^^

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var msg = "";
  var myNode = document.firstChild;
  var breaker = myNode.nodeName;
  var flag = true;
  while(flag)
  {
    msg += myNode.nodeName + " - " + myNode.nodeValue + "; ";
    if(myNode.hasChildNodes())
    {
        myNode = myNode.firstChild;
    }
    else
    {
        while(myNode.nextSibling == null && flag)
        {
            myNode = myNode.parentNode;
            if(myNode.nodeName == breaker)
                flag = false;
        }
        if(flag)
           myNode = myNode.nextSibling;   
    }
  }
  alert(msg);
  </script>
```

(Paste towards the end of your page)